# Trying to submit form on textbox enter press with jquery ajax doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using jquery and ajax, but it fails. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.crazytext').keydown(function (event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/sendchat.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:
                {
                    'from': $('#from').val(),
                    'to': $('#to').val(),
                    'when': $('#when').val(),
                    'msg': $('#chatty').val()
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's simple, I want to submit the form once enter is pressed and send data to sendchat.php without reloading the page. This is the html:

```
<form id="send-message-area" method="POST" action="sendchat.php">
  <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo $me;?>" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="<?php echo $other1;?>" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="when" id="when" value="<?php echo $date;?>" hidden> 
  <textarea class="crazytext" name="msg" id="chatty"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="chat" values="chat" class="crazytext2" hidden>
</form>
```

And if necessary, the php code for sendchat.php

```
$fromuser = $_POST['from'];
$touser = $_POST['to'];
$when = $_POST['when'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$seen = 0;
$addchat = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO scorp_chats (Fromuser, Touser, Messagetime, Message, Seen) VALUES (:fromuser, :touser, :messagetime, :message, :seen)");
$addchat->execute(array(':fromuser' => $fromuser, ':touser' => $touser, ':messagetime' => $when, ':message' => $msg, ':seen' => $seen));
```

That's it really, it's super simple but it fails. If I remove the ajax part completely, it works, but I get redirected to the page, which shouldn't happen.

**SOLUTION (Thanks to Barmar):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.crazytext').keydown(function (event) { // your input(textarea) class
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sendchat.php', // script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#send-message-area").serialize(), // form ID
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#result").text(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent the default submission action:

```
$('.crazytext').keydown(function (event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        event.preventDefault(); // <----
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/sendchat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                'from': $('#from').val(),
                'to': $('#to').val(),
                'when': $('#when').val(),
                'msg': $('#chatty').val()
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Vv6Ae/4/)

Comment: Thank you, after updating the script, enter key still gives me new row in the `<textarea>` instead of submitting the form

Comment: @Barmar what it says here as reply doesn't work (enter makes new line), what is written in the demo does work, but doesn't submit the form I guess since no data is written in the database O_o sorry if I'm too bad with this

Comment: It's submitting the form in my demo, because the `success` function is processing the result. Are you seeing any errors in the Javascript console? What does it show in the Network tab?

Comment: @Barmar console nothing, but network shows this http://puu.sh/60Oi9.png .. It's strange since I'm calling it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map.js"></script>` and it is there...

Comment: `jquery-2.0.3.min.map.js` isn't the jQuery library, it's an optional source map used to help with debugging the minified version. That error can be ignored.

Comment: But the next line in the Network says that the AJAX call was successful.

Comment: I just tested it and it's not showing up in the database, I could give you access if you don't believe me. I tried to get post data in php with `$_POST['msg']` which is input name and `$_POST['chatty']` which is input ID.. Maybe the PHP side is failing? How does ajax pass this data on?

Comment: Go back to the Network tab, click on sendchat.php, then on the Response tab to see what the PHP script is sending back. I'll bet there's a PHP error in there.

Comment: @Barmar just wow :) My session expired but I didn't yet write code to boot user out of the system, so fromuser field is empty..Thanks a bunch for this man, you rock

Comment: @Barmar it actually seems that ajax is sending GET instead of POST.. This is data sample:
`data=from%3Duser1%26to%3Duser2%26when%3D2013%252F12%252F28%2B03%253A38%253A12%26msg%3D123`

Might go crazy :D

Comment: The default content type for POST data is `www-form-urlencoded`, so it looks just like a URL query string.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using both `$_POST` and `$_GET` in the php code to grab data, failed.. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, no ideas. If `$.ajax` and the Network tab say POST, it should be in `$_POST`. You could use `$_REQUEST` so you're not dependent on which it is. But it sounds like there's some other problem.

Comment: I found it, I'm pretty bad.. I had data { data: ... } etc. I'll post the working version as edit to my question. Thanks a bunch again mate!