# submit individual form element with keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a section to show all the answers to a related blog post with comment adding functionality to it

```
 <div id='answerwrapper'>
      <?php foreach($answerStuff as $answer){?>
     <div class='styleanswer'><?php echo $answer->answer_body;?></div>
     <a href='' class='cmnt'>comment</a>
     <form>
           <textarea class='answerComment' placeholder=' add a comment......' ></textarea>
     </form>
     <hr>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

There are multiple answers ,so there should be multiple form element with comment textfield.All i want is to hit enter key to submit each new comment.Problem is i can't figure out how to access specific form when working with specific textarea.I added this line to submit the form but it is not working

```
$(this).form.submit()
```

All i could manage is the following:

```
var comment=$('.cmnt');
var textarea=$('.answerComment');
for(i=0;i<comment.length;i++){
   (function(i){
        $(comment[i]).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(textarea[i]).show();
            $(textarea[i]).keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which===13){
                  $(this).form.submit()   //does nothing, need to submit the particular form element from here
                } 
            });
            $(this).hide();
        });
    })(i);
}
```

can anyone help me with this problem? thanks :)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809831/trying-to-submit-form-on-textbox-enter-press-with-jquery-ajax-doesnt-work) link can help you? It looks like a very similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea is the child of the form so:
    $(this).parent("form").submit();

You can use children() and parent() in jQuery to select children and parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use document.activeElement to select the input box that is currently highlighted. Then submit the value of that element via an Ajax post call to your server on the enter key press.

Something like (untested):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var el = document.activeElement;
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $.ajax({
      url: [your url],
      data: JSON.stringify({name: el.name, value: el.value}),
      method: "POST",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log("yay my untested code worked and stuff was submitted");
    })
  }
});
```